# Model is economically significant, but has negative $R^2$?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, regression, econometrics

I'm reading a paper by Rama Cont that [says](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.13213.pdf) (Page 25):

> We remark that negative R^2 values do not imply that the forecasts are economically meaningless. To emphasize this point, we will incorporate these return forecasts into two common forecast-based trading strategies, and showcase their profitability...

The authors proceed to do just that, showing that a strategy that takes forecast-weighted positions in the stocks under considerations earns economically meaningful profit, despite the forecast model having an OOS r^2 of -0.11 to -0.18.

Intuitively, how can a forecast with a negative r^2 generate positive returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this problem more, I believe I understand what drives this behavior of a negative R^2 and positive PnL. Suppose that you are trading a long-short portfolio (as in the paper), and your out-of-sample data has an unconditional mean that is very different from your in-sample. But, suppose your forecast still ranks the OOS returns accurately while being wrong about the mean. Then your OOS r^2 might be negative, but you don't care because your long-short portfolio pnl is driven by the spread of the returns, not their mean.

I've put together a Colab notebook demonstrating this behavior: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17NHxfxTnO3eEM0UC9j7zkIGNKoHUkXd2?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You ask in a very general way, which makes it hard to pin down without studying the paper since there are plenty of possibilities. Just stating three here:

1. In the specific setup all returns are positive
2. The example is cherry-picked.
3. For the example $r^2$ is an irrelevant indicator.

I'll just discuss option 3. because this may be relevant to a larger audience.

$r^2$ is just one possible summary of the full distribution of outcomes. It may miss totally what is relevant or as expressed by Cont economically meaningful in a specific situation.

To give an intuitive explanation in a simplified setting: Imagine you predict binary outcomes (say 0 being everything is fine and 1 being all hell breaks loose) and the probability of outcome "1" is very low. Then the prediction "always 0" will be very good as measured by all indicators relying on some notion of average fit. But imagine in your specific setup that getting the "1" right is much more desirable than erring in a "0" situation. In that case a strategy may be "good" (predict some "1"s correctly) even though it may mispredict many "0"s on average.

tl;dr: Your quality measure needs to be aligned with your interests other measures can be ignored.